# How to draw sketch on video for a website

Tags: video, web, video-streaming, html5-canvas, html5-video

How to draw sketch or elements like line, circle, square on any video on a webpage ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a canvas onto the video ( explained here : http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/PuttingVideoonCanvas/PuttingVideoonCanvas.html )

Then, you draw your shapes onto the canvas (there are plenty of tutorials, just google it), for example : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial%2FDrawing_shapes